# Annihilator of a Tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, tensors

This is a question I have trouble understanding, hope you can clarify this to me.

**Problem:**

Find the annihilator of the tensor $e_1\wedge e_2+e_3\wedge e_4$ in $V=\left<e_1,\,e_2,\,e_3,\,e_4\right>$.

Comment: For example, $A(e_1^\ast \otimes e_2^\ast +e_2^\ast \otimes e_1^\ast ) + B (e_3^\ast \otimes e_4^\ast +e_4^\ast \otimes e_3^\ast)$

Comment: What are your thoughts on this? :)

Comment: @Shaun: The problem is I don't quite understand what the annihilator means in this context.

Comment: @Hee Kwon Lee: Thanks so much for your reply. But what is meant by the $*$ in the superscript of the basis vectors? I mean, $e_1^*,\,e_2^*$ and so on. I am sorry, but I have very limited knowledge about tensor algebra.

Comment: Your notation makes it seem like you might be working in the exterior algebra rather than the tensor algebra. Can you provide more context? Or a source?

Comment: @rschwieb: I am sorry but I have stated the question exactly as it was given. I don't know any source that I could provide you. This appeared in a practice exam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I interpret the question:

The set of annihilators is

$Ani(e_1 \wedge e_2 + e_3 \wedge e_4) = \{v \in V\ |\ (e_1 \wedge e_2 + e_3 \wedge e_4) \wedge v = 0\}$

Note that any element $v \in V$ can be written as:

$v = \alpha_1 e_1 + \alpha_2 e_2 + \alpha_3 e_3 + \alpha_4 e_4$

So $v \in Ani(e_1 \wedge e_2 + e_3 \wedge e_4)$ implies that

$(e_1 \wedge e_2 + e_3 \wedge e_4) \wedge (\alpha_1 e_1 + \alpha_2 e_2 + \alpha_3 e_3 + \alpha_4 e_4) = 0$

Hence we have that

$\alpha_1 (e_1 \wedge e_3 \wedge e_4) \\
+ \alpha_2 (e_2 \wedge e_3 \wedge e_4) \\
+ \alpha_3 (e_1 \wedge e_2 \wedge e_3) \\
+ \alpha_4 (e_1 \wedge e_2 \wedge e_4) = 0$

Note that $\{(e_1 \wedge e_3 \wedge e_4), (e_2 \wedge e_3 \wedge e_4), (e_1 \wedge e_2 \wedge e_3), (e_1 \wedge e_2 \wedge e_4)\}$ are linearly independent in $\Lambda^3 (V)$ so for the above equation to be $0$ we require that $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = \alpha_3 = \alpha_4 = 0$ hence

$Ani(e_1 \wedge e_2 + e_3 \wedge e_4) = \{0\}$

Answer (score 1):

$\{e_i\}$ is a **dual** basis, i.e., $$e_i^\ast (e_j)=\delta_{ij}.$$ That is any linear map from $V$ to ${\bf R}$ can be written by $$ \sum_{i=1}^4 c_i e_i^\ast$$

Note that $V\otimes V\ (=M_4({\bf R}))$ is vector space whose basis is $\{ e_i\otimes e_j \}$ So $$(e=)\ e_1\wedge e_2+e_3\wedge e_4=e_1\otimes e_2 - e_2\otimes e_1+ e_3\otimes e_4 - e_4\otimes e_3$$ is an element of $V\otimes V$.

Consider dual space $(V\otimes V)^\ast $ whose basis is $\{ e_i^\ast \otimes e_j^\ast \}$

Here annihilator of $(e)$ is a collection $$A=\{f\in (V\otimes V)^\ast | \ f(e)=0\}$$

So $$A=(e_1^\ast\otimes e_2^\ast - e_3^\ast\otimes e_4^\ast)\oplus(e_1^\ast\otimes e_2^\ast + e_2^\ast\otimes e_1^\ast)\oplus (e_3^\ast\otimes e_4^\ast + e_4^\ast\otimes e_3^\ast)\oplus \bigoplus_{(i,j)\in J} e_i^\ast \otimes e_j^\ast $$ where $$J=\{ (i,j)|\ (i,j)\neq (1,2),\ (2,1),\ (3,4),\ (4,3)\} $$

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response. This would take a while for me to understand, due to my limited knowledge about tensor algebra but surely I will try my best. Thanks again.